# xslt change class for every third div

Tags: xslt

I have a question about Xslt mod. I need to change the div class of every 3rd div from "clmn-3 doublespace" to "clmn-3". Tried several tips but could not understand where to add the argument.

```
    <div class="clmn-9 products">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <xsl:if test="$mode = 'edit'">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<div class="webtop">]]></xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:call-template name="ndSitePageList">
    <xsl:with-param name="sPgLstID" select="1" />
    <xsl:with-param name="customTemplate">
    <xsl:for-each select="/ndTemplate/ndSitePageLists/ndList[instanceID=1]/ndSitePage">
    <xsl:call-template name="ndReplaceListSitePageElements">
    <xsl:with-param name="template">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
    <![CDATA[
    <div class="clmn-3 doublespace"> 
    <a href="]]></xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="link"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">  <![CDATA["><img src="]]></xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="/ndTemplate/ndSpgPath"/><xsl:value-of select="srcThumb"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no"><![CDATA["alt="" /></a>
    <div class="clmn-3 shadow"></div>
    <h2>]]></xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="title"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no"><![CDATA[</h2>
    <span class="text">]]></xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="description"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no"><![CDATA[</span>
    </div>
    ]]>
    </xsl:text>
    </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </div>
```

Thank you in advance
Alex

Comment: You forgot to give us the source XML document. The transformation is easy and just a few lines -- but I need the XML document in order to apply it and verify that the correct and wanted results are produced. Please, edit the question and specify the missing, important information.

Answer (score 1):

**I. Here is an example how to specify such processing in XSLT 1.0:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pNewValue" select="'someNewAttribValue'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num[position() mod 3 = 1]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="$pNewValue"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applie on the following XML document** (none was provided in the question!):

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result (every third `num` element has a `class` attribute with a value as specified in an external parameter) is produced**:

```
<nums>
   <num class="someNewAttribValue">01</num>
   <num>02</num>
   <num>03</num>
   <num class="someNewAttribValue">04</num>
   <num>05</num>
   <num>06</num>
   <num class="someNewAttribValue">07</num>
   <num>08</num>
   <num>09</num>
   <num class="someNewAttribValue">10</num>
</nums>
```

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pNewValue" select="'someNewAttribValue'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <nums>
       <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="position() mod 3 eq 1">
         <xsl:sequence select="current-group()[not(current-grouping-key())]"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[current-grouping-key()]"/>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
     </nums>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num">
  <num class="{$pNewValue}"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this XSLT 2.0 transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<nums>
   <num class="someNewAttribValue"/>
   <num>02</num>
   <num>03</num>
   <num class="someNewAttribValue"/>
   <num>05</num>
   <num>06</num>
   <num class="someNewAttribValue"/>
   <num>08</num>
   <num>09</num>
   <num class="someNewAttribValue"/>
</nums>
```